# Ctrl button doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu (64 bit). I saw some discussions about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but in my case I can't do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and, probably, something else (all these cases work fine in other programs, so it's not a keyboard problem). It doesn't work, then it does, then it doesn't again. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they work if you switch to one tab and return to the original? I've read somewhere there might be an issue with the WindowManager on Ubuntu that is interfering with Eclipse, although I've not had the problem myself.

Comment: @JRSofty Thanks, I'll try next time it stops working.

Comment: @JRSofty That is exactly me case. Switching tabs helps.. In my case it has nothing to do with multiple layouts. Started with Juno Service Release 2. I can't find more on google. Do you remember a link/ search term. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @alfonx I can't remember where I read this as it's been almost a year ago. If I run across it again I'll post the link.

Comment: this link is useful for me to cltr+space in eclipse,
http://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema?rq=1

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Switching tabs helps in most of the times but not always. Is there a real fix somewhere? This is very frustrating ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am also using 64-bit Ubuntu (12.04 now, 11.10 before that) and Eclipse. I was having similar problems like what you are describing, until I realized that keyboard input method/layout settings actually matter in Ubuntu (while it does not in Mac OS or Windows) while using copy/paste. If you are using two keyboard layouts (e.g. I am using English and Bulgarian), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> will not work with the non-English layout. If it does no work, double-check the current keyboard layout.
It took me awhile to figure that out - hope it would help you too.

Comment: Interesting, it does works fine on 32-bit with English and German keyboard setup however.

Comment: I would assume it has something to do with the character that you are actually typing. I guess in the German layout `C` and `V` are still the same characters, while in Bulgarian those are `Ц` and `Ж`.

Comment: It seems to be a reason, but not the only one. Sometimes indeed shortcuts don't work due to wrong keybord layout. But sometimes they don't work even with English layout and on both Ubuntu and Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978159/eclipse-shortcut-keys-are-not-working-suddenly-in-windows/28395104#28395104

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the same problem rebuilding my workspace <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on Windows

Comment: Hmm... the shortcut doesn't seem to work for me.   ;^)

Comment: `Ctrl` button doesn't work in Eclipse, so let's try `Ctrl+B`... Something seems wrong here...

Comment: No idea why but rebuilding my workspace worked for me too. For those who want to try this remember that you can do this under `Project -> Build Project` if `Control + B` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## Similar problem

Looks like there are some key combination which screw up with the focus in the eclipse editor. Try using the shortcut for Focus Return

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>