# Eclipse shortcut keys are not working suddenly in Windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

Eclipse shortcut keys are not working suddenly in Windows. Even basic needed shortcut keys like 'ctrl + F' and 'ctrl + c' don't work. I hope that if eclipse is restarted, it would work, but I cannot restart as my applications are running in eclipse. I ensured that this is happening only in eclipse, not in other applications in my computer.

Comment: I'm having this issue. I found that bringing the help up (press F1) solves it.

Comment: For me going to another project (same workspace), and CTRL + D worked. Then came back, and noticed it works in the initial project too!

Comment: I have the same issue in eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) - solved it by closing all open sourcecode, opening a java class in a different project and going back to the project i was working in it suddenly was repaired

Answer (score 62):

My problem was solved when I restored defaults values of my Keys.
Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys.
Then, click Restore Defaults button at the bottom, and restart Eclipse.
I am using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: I had the same problem with STS(Spring Tool Suite version 3.83) The above solution fixed it.

Comment: I did this and restarted and they were back.

Comment: If some shortcuts work, but others don't, sort the table on the Keys preference page by Binding and check for duplicates. If there aren't duplicates, It could be that your operating system or windowing environment already use them.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Turned out that a shortcut of my Radeon Software overwrote the shortcut of eclipse so it wouldn't trigger in eclipse anymore. After rebinding the shortcut in my Radeon Software it also worked again in eclipse.

Answer (score 43):

This is a bug in Eclipse Juno, restarting Eclipse does solve it temporarily, I'll try an dig out the bug report.

Bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385278

Comment from bug description...

> I am also facing a lot of problems regarding the keyboard shortcuts.
>   The issue is intermittent and all of a sudden most of the key board
>   shortcuts(specifically f3, ctrl+D, ctrl+O ) stop working unless I
>   restart my IDE.

Comment: Facing same issue in Version: Kepler Service Release 2. Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: Restarting Eclipse and even rebooting doesn't help for me; shortcuts still gone.

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.4 Luna and am having this same issue

Comment: As a developer with multiple workspaces, I just confirmed that this is workspace dependent.  My one workspace no longer has keyboard shortcuts, and my other does.  Using Eclipse Luna

Comment: I didn't have backup of the file and I had to undo some code :(

Comment: I just got this problem with Eclipse Luna. Creating a new workspace didn't help, neither restarting whole computer. I'm now in process of copying a fresh copy of Eclipse Luna.

Comment: I had this bug today with Eclipse Mars (Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) Build id: 20150924-1200). Setting the Scheme (Window Menu -> Preferences -> General -> Keys) to "emacs", then back to "Default" and restarting eclipse fixed it for me.

Comment: For me as I installed the latest neon-2 this issue shows up also, fix by goto Window -> Perspective -> Custome Perspective -> shortcuts tab and toggle the checkbox for corresponding shortcuts.

Comment: Theres a quicker answer for this below instead of restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 20):

Based on the link posted by david99world

Changing perspective and going back does also solve this, that does looks like is a focus problem.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me also - *much* faster than restarting my IDE every time this bug crops up!

Comment: That worked for me when the restarting didn't.

Comment: Window > Perspective > Rest Perspective...  also works for me.

Answer (score 7):

My problem was solved this way: 
Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

and look at the "Scheme:" control. Change it to "Default". If only that doesnt do it for you, in the field "Binding:" leave it blank.

For me it worked.

Comment: If its already at default, change it to something else, close the dialog, open the keys again and change it to default. Worked fine here!