# Sometimes keyboard shortcuts do not work in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Couple of weeks ago I installed complete ADT bundle from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). this comes up with `Android Developer Tool (Eclipse) Build: v22.3.0`. Sometimes its shortcut keys do not work. If I close my eclipse and start it again, then it works fine, and if I use to keep work then after some times it again gives the same problem. Is that any bug or issue or did I do something wrong?

Any suggestion?

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978159/eclipse-shortcut-keys-are-not-working-suddenly-in-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bug. Happens on windows or sometimes on my ubuntu too. I can not even do a `Ctrl + S` to save the file. Restarts solves the problem. Its an eclipse bug.