# In Spring Tools Sutie 4, why Alt + Shift + Q, O not work?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I am using Spring Tools Suite 4 (based on Eclipse IDE).

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.8.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202009151856

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2020 Pivotal, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit https://spring.io/tools

This product includes software developed by the
Eclipse Foundation https://www.eclipse.org

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation https://www.apache.org
```

Why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> not work?

I press 3 keys at same time: <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>. Then I keep key <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, move finger from <kbd>Q</kbd> to <kbd>O</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Maybe press alt, shift and q, release all those buttons and press o?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: @dan1st , I do like your guide, it does not work. How to get log?

Comment: Help>About this Product>Configuration>Configuration Log or something like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18978159/10871900 Did you try dwitching your perspective and switching it back afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and then release everything, a small window appears at the bottom right of the main window with the list of views that can be shown using this key sequence - now press <kbd>O</kbd> for the outline.